# Active Record .includes with where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to avoid an N+1 query by using `includes`, but I need to filter out some of the child records. Here's what I have so far:

```
Column.includes(:tickets).where(board_id: 1, tickets: {sprint_id: 10})
```

The problem is that only Columns containing Tickets with `sprint_id` of 10 are returned. I want to return *all* Columns with board_id of 1, and pre-fetch tickets only with a `sprint_id` of 10, so that `column.tickets` is either an empty list of a list of Ticket objects with `sprint_id` 10.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to implement what You want in one statement. At least for me. I would do it as such, first, remove tickets from where statement. Second, when You call `column.tickets` add at the end `.where(sprint_id: 10)`. Other than that, I would probably write up a custom sql.

Comment: Gotcha. The problem is that that creates an N+1 query where N is the number of columns, no?

Comment: If it does, try adding `Column.all` ?

Comment: Don't believe that these queries should cause N+1: `@columns = Column.includes(:tickets).where(board_id: 1)` and then
`@columns` or `@columns.tickets.where(sprint_id: 10)`

Comment: Seems to be causing N+1 for me in the rails console. It would have to be doing the `where` clause using in-memory Ruby code instead of running a SQL query, but I see it outputting `SELECT ... FROM tickets WHERE sprint_id =  10` for each iteration.

Comment: Why do you only want to prefetch a subset of tickets?

Comment: On a side note naming your model Column is asking for trouble due to the risk of collision with ActiveRecord's methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how includes is intended to work. When you add a where clause it applies to the entire query and not just loading the associated records.

One way of doing this is by flipping the query backwards:

```
columns = Ticket.eager_load(:columns)
                .where(sprint_id: 10, columns: { board_id: 1 })
                .map(&:column)
                .uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

`Column.includes(:tickets).where(board_id: 1, tickets: {sprint_id: 10})` makes two SQL queries. One to select the columns that match the specified where clause, and another to select and load the tickets that their `column_id` is equal to the id of the matched columns.

To get all the related columns without loading unwanted tickets, you can do this:

```rb
columns = Column.where(board_id: 1).to_a
tickets = Ticket.where(column_id: columns.map(&:id), sprint_id: 10).to_a
```

This way you won't be able to call `#tickets` on each column (as it will again make a database query and you'll have the N+1 problem) but to have a similar way of accessing a column's tickets without making any queries you can do something like this:

```rb
grouped_tickets = tickets.group_by(&:column_id)
columns.each do |column|
  column_tickets = grouped_tickets[column.id]
  # Do something with column_tickets if they're present.
end
```

Comment: Be careful with those `to_a` calls, it's a bad practice to load everything in memory without knowing the amount of records. Use `Column.where(board_id: 1).pluck(:id)` to get the ids in a more performant way (it may require one more sql query later to iterate over the records but should have a big impact)